# External drive(s) not writable anymore

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, permissions, ownership

I recently wanted to try Tails on my Macbook with El Capitan 10.11.6 installed. So I followed the documentation and installed the Tails-image at one point on an external USB flash drive. After start-up, I held option, but I wasn't shown. Having had problems with that specific drive in the past, I tried different drives: A new usb flash drive and also an external HDD. 
So I have these three drives with a Tails image on them, none of them shows while I startup and I want to format them again. But all of them can't be formatted anymore with disk utility. I tried to do it with terminal, but didn't work either. When I click on one of them while they are mounted and choose 'get info', there is no possibility to chance anything. Permissions are on write  only, but there's neither a lock to open nor any other possibility to change permissions.
I also tried to do it with terminal. Missing ownership seems to be the problem, but when I try to enable it, I get the following error message:
'Error enountered enabling user/group ownership: The underlying task reported failure on exit (-69860)'

Is there anything else I can do? Are my drives trashed now?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I've finally found a solution for the problem... while everything I tried in OS X failed miserably, the drives worked all fine in Ubuntu and could be formatted again without any problems.